# AWK split file after Y occurs X times

Tags: shell, awk

I am trying to split a big file into multi files. If the "tag" was found 1000 times.

This works but write a new file for every tag. How should I place the counter ?

```
awk '{print $0 RS > NR ".txt" ; close(NR".txt") }' RS="</tag>" big_file.txt
```

for example :

tag> 
   bla1 
   blub 
/tag>

tag> 
   bla2 
   blub 
/tag>

tag> 
   bla3 
   blub 
/tag>

tag> 
   bla4 
   blub 
/tag>

tag> 
   bla5 
   blub 
/tag>

tag> 
   bla6 
   blub 
/tag>

What I want :

FILE 1 : 
tag> 
   bla1 
   blub 
/tag> 
tag> 
   bla2 
   blub 
/tag> 
tag> 
   bla3 
   blub 
/tag>

FILE 2: 
tag> 
   bla4 
   blub 
/tag> 
tag> 
   bla5 
   blub 
/tag> 
tag> 
   bla6 
   blub 
/tag>

and so on

thanks a lot

Comment: What's the "tag"? An example would be useful, preferably with less than 1000 lines!

Comment: hope the example is ok :-)

Comment: @mickmack - What I understood is you wanted to split a big file into many small files with no small file have string "tag" more then 1000 times. Is it correct?

Comment: No, I want some small files, but not for every part between tag> and /tag>. The tag> and /tag> should be included. It is a very big xml file that I want to split.

Comment: Sorry I am new in awk, hope the question is not total nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

Your command

```
awk '{print $0 RS > NR ".txt" ; close(NR".txt") }' RS="</tag>" big_file.txt
```

works different for my version of awk (I use mawk 1.3.3). Instead of splitting of **big_file.txt** into many files for each pattern

```
tag>
...
/tag>
```

it writes the whole context of **big_file.txt** into file **1.txt**.

But in order to solve your problem you can try to use **sprintf** function. For me the following command worked:

```
awk 'num = 2 { file = sprintf("small_file%s.txt", int(delim / num)); print > file; } /^\/tag>$/ { delim++ }'   < big_file.txt
```

Here variable **num** is the desired number of occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot in good conscience condone the use of `</tag>` for the value of RS (RS is only well defined when it is a single character, or empty, although it can be longer in some implementations.  But more importantly, parsing xml this way is extremely fragile), but if you have a solution you like using NR that write a new file for each record, you can simply replace `NR` with `int(NR/1000)` to get the behavior you desire.